# ¿Cómo pasar props a un componente de styled-component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo el componente `<Button />` que le quiero pasa propiedades básicas para después reutilizarlas en un nuevo componente que genero con `styled-component`.

```js
import React from "react"
import styled from "styled-component"

// button con estilos
import Button from "path/components/Button"

const ButtonRed = styled(Button)`
  color: red;
`

export const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <ButtonRed type="text" variant="default" disable={false}>Uno</ButtonRed>
      <ButtonRed type="text" variant="default" disable={false}>Dos</ButtonRed>
      <ButtonRed type="text" variant="default" disable={false}>Tres</ButtonRed>
    </>
  )
}
```

Y lo que quiero hacer es que en vez de pasarle las propiedades de `text`, `variant` y `disable` a todos los botones repetidamente, se lo setee directamente en el `ButtonRed` creado con `styled()`.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que `styled-component` solo interactúa con el atributo del estilo de los elementos, te recomiendo usar un [`HOC`](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) para crear un  botón con los atributos que buscas, inclusive podrías cambiarlos agregando parámetros. Por otro lado para no escribirlo, creo que lo mejor sería hacer un map del array de diferentes strings que quieres en los botones.

```
import React from "react"
import styled from "styled-component"


// button con estilos
import Button from "path/components/Button"

const ButtonRed = styled(Button)`
  color: red;
`

function boton(texto){
    return <ButtonRed key={texto} type="text" variant="default" disable={false}>{texto}</ButtonRed>
} 

export const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {["Uno","Dos","Tres"].map(t=>boton(t))}
    </>
  )
}
```

Espero haber podido entender tu pregunta, estoy atento a cualquier comentario o duda que tengas.

### Update

Encontré en la documentación la manera de pasar props utilizando el método constructor [.attrs()](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#attaching-additional-props), esto parece ser lo que andas buscando:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-component";

// button con estilos
import Button from "./Button";

const ButtonRed = styled(Button).attrs({
  key: "texto",
  type: "text",
  variant: "default",
  disable: false
})`
  color: red;
`;


export const MyComponent = () => {
  return <>{["Uno", "Dos", "Tres"].map((t) => (<ButtonRed>{t}</ButtonRed>))}</>;
};
```

Comment: Yo esperaba una forma en el que puedas pasarle una opción más al `stlyed` (tipo `styled(Button, defaultProps)`) o algo componentizado.

Comment: Creo que encontré lo que buscabas.

Comment: Eso lo probé pero no funciona.